# Problem accesing a file when deploying in tomcat a java/flex application

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, deployment

I have two applications: a client in flex and a server in Java. When I deploying the application inside flex builder with the tomcat server inside as well, everything works fine. But now I'm trying to deploy in apache tomcat outside the flex/eclipse builder and I have a problem.

I think the problem is with relative/absolute paths but I do not know how to resolve it.
In my Java application I have to access a database and a get a file from it. I use a properties to set a path where I want to download that files like this:

```
pacs.ruta=C:\\resources\\
```

And then I need to access to that file so in use this code:

`fin = new FileInputStream(pacsRuta+""+f.getName());`

where f.getName() gives me the name of the file so I get the path of the file with the path I set in pacs.ruta and the files name.
I do not know why it does not work. I tried to put

```
pacs.ruta=/resources/
```

to associate with a folder in my application but It does not work.

Could someone give me an advice? Do you think it is the problem? Because the whole application works fine deploying in a tomcat server outside the flex/eclipse builder but when this code is called the application does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in WEB-INF/classes so it's in CLASSPATH and use `getResourceAsStream()` to read it from the servlet context.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I tried to do it but probably I do not know how to do it. I do not use servlets, it's just a java a application. Is it needed to set something in server.xml inside catalina?? I read something about context-path but i do not also where I have to put it. I just copy my webContent files inside the webapps in the tomcat and trying to deploy.

Comment: I trying using String s=ConsultaPACS.class.getResource("");s = s.substring(6); to set the path. ConsultaPACS is the class where I made the call to receive the file and that's the path where my databases files are downloaded.

Comment: What good is a Java application running on Catalina without servlets or JSPs?  No, you should be loading it from the servlet context.  I'd also recommend doing it using a ServletContextLoaderListener that you configure in your web.xml

Comment: Sorry I thougth you mean servlet applet.Its true I have to used servlets to get blazeds work and I configure them in web.xml: <servlet><servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
  <display-name>RDSDispatchServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>flex.rds.server.servlet.FrontEndServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>useAppserverSecurity</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>    
  <init-param>
   <param-name>messageBrokerId</param-name>
   <param-value>_messageBroker</param-value>
  </init-param> <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup></servlet>

Comment: Can you explain me more how I can use getResourceAsStream()? I make a .xml file with the context path and put it inside catalina/localhost but it does not work. Probably it's something of configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it works, it was a problem with permisions.